# Wrong version of SQLitePCLRaw.core used (1.1.13 instead of 2.0.2) in Xamarin.iOS project causes build error

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a build error in Xamarin.iOS project:

`MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.String SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_errmsg(SQLitePCL.sqlite3)', referenced from the method 'System.String SQLite.SQLite3::GetErrmsg(SQLitePCL.sqlite3)' in 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.13.388, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'. [/Users/[Redacted]/[Redacted]/[Redacted]/src/[Redacted].iOS/[Redacted].iOS.csproj]`

Higher in the build log I can see that different version of SQLitePCLRaw.core is used than the one provided in csproj, i.e.:

`LinkerPleaseInclude.cs(179,25): warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.1.610, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535' used by 'SQLite-net' matches identity 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.2.669, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535' of 'SQLitePCLRaw.core', you may need to supply runtime policy [/Users/[Redacted]/[Redacted]/[Redacted]/src/[Redacted].iOS/[Redacted].iOS.csproj]`

This, however, is not saying about downgrade to 1.1.13. When I don't reference this method in `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` I don't get this warning at all.

In my csproj I have set:

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-sqlcipher">
  <Version>1.7.302-beta</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="akavache.sqlite3">
  <Version>6.9.10</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher">
  <Version>2.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core">
  <Version>2.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

So even though I have explicitly set `SQLitePCLRaw.core` version to 2.0.2 in csproj a different version is used by the compiler. How can I *supply runtime policy* as stated in the warning?

Comment: From what I understand there is a string the version 1.1.13.xx that is unavailable in the versions that come after which is causing this issue. Is it mandatory for you to upgrade to the latest version of this package? Because i have SQLITE in my project which works just fine!

Comment: Can you please try the solution [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6734#issuecomment-519322018), the error message there is similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT for pointing out the suggestion. This unfortunately didn't work for me. I had to downgrade several packages to make it work. Please see full answer for that.

Comment: Ok, you can mark your answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as usually related to dependencies. I had to downgrade them and had to assure compatibility.

Currently I use:

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-sqlcipher" Version="1.6.292" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher" Version="1.1.13" />
<PackageReference Include="akavache.sqlite3" Version="6.5.1" />
```

It seems that the lowest Akavache supporting 1.1.13 of SQLitePCL is 6.5.1 and any higher even tough I've been supplying 2.0.2 was using wrong version.